# How can I update the second-to-last row?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update the second-to-last row in a table given a set of conditions. If it was a `SELECT` query it would look like this:

```
SELECT col_1 FROM table_1 WHERE id = id_# ORDER BY timestamp_col DESC LIMIT  1,1
```

However, I get an error when I do the following but it's the behavior I want:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET col_1 = value_# ORDER BY timestamp_col DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

I'm aware I can write this

```
UPDATE table_1 SET col_1 = value_# ORDER BY timestamp_col DESC LIMIT 1
```

But I can't figure out how to get the second-to-last row to update given the set of conditions.

What is the correct query to update the second-to-last row?

Comment: `UPDATE table_1 SET col_1 = value_# ORDER BY timestamp_col DESC LIMIT 1,1` Why is here an error? What is an error? Because it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support the "offset" feature in the `LIMIT` clause for [**UPDATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) or [**DELETE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) operations.

But it ***is*** supported for [**SELECT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) statements.

So what you can do to get around this is wrap the offset `LIMIT` selection in a joined subselect, ***then*** update only the row where the `id` and `timestamp_col` equals the joined `id` and `timestamp_col` like so:

```
UPDATE table_1 a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, timestamp_col
    FROM table_1
    WHERE id = <id>
    ORDER BY timestamp_col DESC
    LIMIT 1,1
) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.timestamp_col = b.timestamp_col
SET a.col_1 = <value>
```